# Cakephp, weird performance issues

Tags: cakephp

I've asked this question all over the web, but nobody has replied so far.

I have a Cake app on a live server. The problem is everything seems to be cached.

Let's say you're on the index page, hit "delete" link to delete a record, and you're redirected back to the index. The "deleted" record is still shown. If you hit the refresh button, the record is no longer shown and the flash message appears.

And it's like this all over the site.

I've disabled caching in config/core.php, sessions are pure cakephp (works the same with database and php sessions), debug is 0.

Server is PHP5.

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: Well, what about setting debug to 2? does it say anything?

Could you also post your delete() method?

Does this happen for all the models?

Comment: another suggestion: try deleting all the files in /tmp/cache. Many weird Cake behaviors stem from there.

Comment: Use pastebin to post your delete message and please also post your SQL log (so we can see if it's the db that's being slow, or your app)

Comment: It's associated with all actions, not just delete. And it affects all browsers, not just one specific. Debug:2 does nothing, no errors are thrown in any case

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but I had the same problem with Ajax calls, which didn't update their element correctly (perhaps because of a typo). Are you using Ajax perhaps?

Comment: No AJAX. I sort of fixed the problem by setting debug to 2, and security to low, while forcing no-caching with php headers. This is a horrible solution but it works

Comment: Argh, debug 2 on a production site...

Answer (score 1):

What is your browser? I use Opera and I admit it doesn't manage the cache the way I'd want it to. I have to refresh, while Firefox works perfectly (or at least reload the page the way I'd expect it to while I'm debugging)

Answer (score 0):

(from twitter @IvanBernat) have you tried to add meta tag for killing browser cache? use firebug and see if browser get 304 code for your file